# MS SQL : Convert datetime to web standards complient TIME format

Tags: sql-server, html, datetime, input, time

#### Official formatting for time input fields according to the web specification.

W3 seems to indicate that accepted formats are:

```
23:20:50.52
17:39:57
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.time.html

---

### QUESTIONS

1. Should time input fields should be populated fully with seconds and milliseconds or is `00:00` acceptable?

---

2. From MS SQL iS **ISO8601 CONVERT 126** the correct format or is **SQL CONVERT 108**  `hh:mm:ss` acceptible?

   `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[MyDate]),108) AS [MyDate]`

[Click for list of SQL CONVERT() Functions](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp)

---

3. What is an appropriate way to pull a correctly formatted time field from an MSSQL datetime field using **convert 126**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document clearly states the accepted format for time values:

> Value: A valid *partial-time* as defined in [RFC 3339].

The [relevant part of RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339#section-5.6) has the following definitions:

```
time-hour       = 2DIGIT  ; 00-23
time-minute     = 2DIGIT  ; 00-59
time-second     = 2DIGIT  ; 00-58, 00-59, 00-60 based on leap second
                          ; rules
time-secfrac    = "." 1*DIGIT

partial-time    = time-hour ":" time-minute ":" time-second
                  [time-secfrac]
```

which means that *partial-time* consists of hours (2 digits, 24-hour notation), followed by a colon (`:`), followed by minutes (2 digits), followed by another colon, followed by seconds, then *optionally* followed by a decimal fraction (a decimal point followed by 1 or more digits).

So, seconds are mandatory, but the fractional part is optional, which means that `00:00` is not a valid *partial-time* as defined by RFC 3339, but `00:00:00` is fine, as are `00:00:00.0`, `00:00:00.000`, `00:00:00.0000` and other variations.

As for the `CONVERT` function, the 108 style matches the specification and if you do not need milliseconds (or nanoseconds or whatever), it is all right to use it. If you want milliseconds, you can use style 114 and replace the last `:` with a `.` or you can use styles 121 or 126 and extract just the time portion. How to extract it? Well, `CONVERT` would give you a string, so just apply `SUBSTRING` to it with correct arguments.